# Incrementing pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Why are the two following code segments not equivalent?

```
void print (char* s) {
  if (*s == '\0')
     return;
    print(s+1);
   cout << *s;
}

void print (char* s) {
  if (*s == '\0')
     return;
    print(++s);
   cout << *s;
}
```

Comment: who says they are not equivilent?

Comment: Did you actually compiled it and see whether they are equivalent or not ?

Comment: oh boy, i wanted to asked difference between s+1 and ++s

Comment: @user - Ok... tried my part in making you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like the OP changed `print(s++)` to `print(++s)`, which is hugely different, here's an explanation for this new version.

In the first example, you have:

```
print(s+1);
cout << *s;
```

s+1 does not modify s. So if s is 4, and you `print(s+1)`, afterwards s will still be 4.

```
print(++s);
cout << *s;
```

In this case, ++s modifies the local value of s. It increments it by 1. So if it was 4 before `print(++s)`, it will be *5* afterwards.

In both cases, a value equivalent to s+1 would be passed to the print function, causing it to print the next character.

So the difference between the 2 functions is that the first one will recursively print character #0, then 1, 2, 3, ..., while the second function prints 1, 2, 3, 4, ... (it skips the first character and prints the "\0" afterwards).

Example:
For the `s+1` version, `print("hello")` will result in `h` `e` `l` `l` `o`
For the `++s` version, `print("hello")` will result in `e` `l` `l` `o` `\0`

Answer (score 7):

The `++` operator increments the pointer value, but then returns the original value ... so `print(s++)` will print the value of `s` before the increment, since even though it adds a value of 1 to `s`, making the value stored at `s` equal to `s+1`, it still *returns* the original value of `s` as the *result* of the operation.  On the otherhand `print(s+1)` prints the value after the increment, but very importantly does not modify the original value of `s`.  So the *result* of the statement `s+1` is just a new temporary pointer value ... the original value of `s` is not modified.

Furthermore, since you've incremented and changed the value of `s` with the `++` operator, when you call `cout`, you're now printing the value to wherever the new pointer is pointing (this could cause a crash or segmentation fault if you're not careful and there's no user accessible memory at the new memory location `s` is pointing to).  With `s+1`, the value of `s` remains unmodified, so the result of `cout` will be to wherever `s` was originally pointing.

---

### Edit:

As Michael points out, this is actually a recursive function, so the second example simply keeps calling `print()` with the same argument, since as mentioned before, the returned value from `s++` is the original value of `s`.  That means you'll end up with a stack overflow at some point and just crash unless the value that `s` pointed to was already the NULL character.

Comment: Actually, the second version will not print anything, but will eventually cause a stack overflow unless the string is empty (or, with incredibly clever optimization on the compiler's part, loop infinitely). The method calls itself with the same argument it received, due to using post-increment instead of pre-increment.

Comment: `++s` isn't the same as `s++`, so the second example won't cause a stack overflow. Did he edit the question and change it from `s++`?

Comment: Must have, since my answer is not the only answer to refer to the `s++` statement, so I don't think I was reading it wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Both of the expressions `s++` and `s+1` are to do with increasing the position of the pointer itself, not the value contained at the pointer locations
2. The value of `s++` is just `s`, and the value of `s+1` is, well, one position further on than `s`!
3. The value of `s` after executing `s++` is one position further on than it was before. After using `s+1`, the value of `s` is unchanged.

Therefore the order they print out the letters is reversed!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain an example of pre and post increment from which you can solve the question posted yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int num)
{
    std::cout << num << "\n" ;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 10 ;

    foo( number++ ) ;
    foo( ++number ) ;
    foo( number + 1 ) ;

    getchar() ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

**Output:**

> 10
>   12
>   13

**Why 10?**

```
foo( number++ ) ;
```

*Post-increment* operation is done on **number**. Meaning, value of **number** is first passed to `foo` and then the value of **number** is incremented upon `foo` return. So, after function return, **number** is 11.

**Why 12?**

```
foo( ++number ) ;
```

*Pre-increment* operation is done on **number**. Meaning, before even call to `foo`, the value of `number` is incremented to 12. And then it is passed to `foo`. So, even after the function return, **number** is still 12.

**Why 13?**

It's just straight forward. Value of **number** is not modified but passed a value adding 1 to the value of **number**. In this process, **number** is not modified. So, even after function return, **number** is still 12.

Hope this helps to solve the problem yourself ( though in your case it is paper-pencil exercise ) :)

Comment: @user - Since you need to understand recursion and also the scope of the variables in the recursion tree, this thread should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852237/question-on-c-recursion-and-local-variables/5852254#5852254